# awareness about vs awareness of

Tags: grammar

The italic text in the sentence is wrong. We are supposed to correct the error. This question came out in my school examinations.

> The best place to create awareness *from* the environment is in schools.

I replaced *from* to *about*. My teacher marked this as wrong, saying the correct answer is *of*. Her argument was that the sentence "to be aware of" uses *of* instead of *about*.

Which word is the correct, more appropriate word to use?

Comment: Although we say "are you aware *of* this?" and not "are you aware about this?", once we get to the abstract noun *awareness*, you will find native speakers saying things like "We want to increase awareness about the environment".  "Awareness of" and "Awareness about" are different things.  "about" suggests "the *issues* of environmentalism".

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(awareness+about)&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28awareness%20about%29%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

'Be aware of' means to know or understand. See this [link](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/be+aware+of).
When we consider awareness as knowledge, it is better to put 'of' after it.
Also, the most commonly used word after 'awareness' is 'of'. Check this [link](https://www.manhattanprep.com/gmat/forums/awareness-of-about-t6770.html):
Therefore, following sentence is correct.

> The best place to create awareness ***of*** the environment is in schools.

Here, I think 'in' is wrong, and we can better write the sentence as:

> The best place to create awareness ***of*** the environment is schools.

Hope this helps.